# Unable to use GMP with Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I have installed GMP on ubuntu. I download GMP-6.1.2 from "https://gmplib.org".Then I extracted it in Home folder and installed like:

```
1. cd gmp-6.1.2
2../configure
3. make
4. sudo make install
5. make check
```

I checked,gmp was installed in "/usr/local" and I opened omnet and I change these paths:
I entered Properties project:

```
1. in (c/c++ build | environment | path ), I added : 
(/usr/local/include:/usr/local/lib) then I applied.

2. in (c/c++ General | paths and symbols | includes),I added 
(/usr/local/include) in assembly, GNU c, GNU C++.then I applied.
```

At ( (c/c++ General | paths and symbols | Library paths). I added (/usr/local/lib). Then I applied.

Also ( (c/c++ General | paths and symbols | libraries). I wrote "gmpxx" and "gmp". Then I applied.

```
3. in (omnet++ | Makemake | select "src" folder | select Options | 
custom | makefrag ) I added "EXTRA_OBJS=-lgmp". Then I applied them 
and OK.
```

After that,I built my project and I received these errors :

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Error refreshing Makefiles: /home/mar/Desktop/omnet_proj/id_2/test_independent/mixim-2.3/src/EXTRA_OBJS=-lgmp (No such file or directory)    mixim-2.3        Unknown    Makefile Problem
>
> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Program "gcc" not found in PATH    mixim-2.3        [Discovery Options] page in project properties    C/C++ Problem
>
> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Program "make" not found in PATH    mixim-2.3             C/C++ Problem

I must say I am using MIXIM in Omnet++.
I don't know what is going on?

Could you please help me?

Thank you in advance of your help.

Comment: Please provide example code and error messages. Describe exactly what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry,I don't have any error,I have installed GMP correctly.I need to use GMP in Omnet but I don't have any function of GMP in Omnet.(like "mpf_sub"). I wanted to know how can I use GMP in Omnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can do that.

I have installed gmp in ubuntu. Then I added "gmp.h" and "gmpXX.h" to my project.

After that,I went to project properties | omnet++ | select SRC | Options | link | Additional libraries to link with:(-l option) and I inserted these two Option:
gmpxx , gmp .

Also,I added "/usr/local/include" in "paths and symbols(in project properties) | includes " and "/usr/local/lib" in " paths and symbols | library paths ".

After that,I added "/usr/include" in "paths and symbols(in project properties) | includes " and "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu" in " paths and symbols | library paths ".

And I built my project without any error.

At last,I run dear Jurzy D's example without any error.

I did not change any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have installed `libgmp` using `sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev` in your `OMNeT++` project you have to do:

1. In header file (*.h) of simple module where you want to use `gmp` add:

   ```
   #include <gmp.h>
   ```
2. Go to `Project Properties`, choose `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | select `src` | `Options` | `Custom` | `Makefrag` and write:

   ```
   EXTRA_OBJS=-lgmp
   ```

To check you can add the following code somewhere in your source file, for example in `initialize()`:

```
    mpz_t a, b, c;
    mpz_init_set_str(a, "123", 10);
    mpz_init_set_str(b, "458", 10);
    mpz_init(c);
    mpz_add(c, a, b);

    char * ctxt = mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, c);
    EV << "c=" << ctxt << std::endl;  // print the result
    mpz_clear(a);
    mpz_clear(b);
    mpz_clear(c);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but it doesn't work. I add "EXTRA_OBJS=-lgmp",then I had this error in Makemake Options: (Target name contains illegal characters). I don't know,if it is important to know or not.I use MIXIM in Omnet.

Comment: Are you able to build MIXIM without gmp? Could you provide more logs with your error as well as content of makefrag file?

Comment: I could build MIXIM without gmp. In fact,I run my project on Mixim very well but I had problem of Big integers so I had to install GMP. Could you please tell me how I can access in Makefrag file?Thanks.

Comment: Sorry,when I build MIXIM I have this message: (/mixim-2.3/Makefile seems to be a hand-written makefile, refusing to overwrite it. Please delete it or move it away.
/mixim-2.3/Makefile seems to be a hand-written makefile, refusing to overwrite it. Please delete it or move it away.
)

Comment: I have updated my answer. After editing properties the `makefrag` file will be created in src. Do you see `makefrag`?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have makefrag in SRC. I did your suggestion and I got this error:Error refreshing makefiles,reason:  (/home/mar/Desktop/omnet_proj/id_2/test_independent/mixim-2.3/src/EXTRA_OBJS=-lgmp (No such file or directory)
)

Comment: I thought this is better to explain every things. So I have updated my question.