# How to use lpsolve in omnet++ simple modules

Tags: c++, omnet++, lpsolve

lpsolve can be called from a c++ program with main() but I am unable to use it in handlemesage() or any other user-defined method in omnet++ simulation.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: followed the procedure given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052470/unable-to-use-gmp-with-omnet and Finally it worked !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to project properties --> omnet++ --> select SRC --> Options --> link --> Additional libraries to link with: ( -l option) and insert lpsolve55 and ok

[Screenshot of the step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK7ax.png)

[Screenshot of the step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHxZd.png)